# Convert Resulting Rdd into HashMap

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hashmap

I need to convert rdd into hashMap. I am having data in RDD like below:

(FRUIT, List(Apple,Banana,Mango)) (VEGETABLE, List(Potato,Tomato))

I am having below code currently

```
object JsonParse {

 def main(args: Array[String]){


val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("JsonParse").setMaster("local"))

val arr = Array(("FRUIT",List("Apple","Banana","Mango")),("VEGETABLE", List("Potato","Tomato")))

val Rdd = sc.parallelize(arr)
```

how to proceed further??

Answer (score 4):

```
rdd.collectAsMap() // Map(VEGETABLE -> List(Potato, Tomato), FRUIT -> List(Apple, Banana, Mango))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
rdd.collect.toMap
```

to convert it to a `Map`. Action `collect` gathers the contents of the `rdd` locally to the master node.